# fromEvent observable emit a value only on hit of enter key

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm following this [Material data table tutorial](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/) tutorial which implements observable for filtering table.

I would like to modify this code to do paginate only on hit of enter key.

```
fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement,'keyup')
   .pipe(
        debounceTime(150),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap(() => {
            this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
            this.loadLessonsPage();
        })
    )
    .subscribe();
```

I'm trying to emits fromEvent on hit of key 'Enter' instead of any key up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use filter operator:

```
fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement,'keyup')
   .pipe(
        debounceTime(150),
        filter((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.keyCode === 13),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap(() => {
            this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
            this.loadLessonsPage();
        })
    )
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: Visual code complaining about filter : Cannot find name 'filter'. Did you mean 'File'?

Comment: you will have to import it as: `import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';`